# How to properly check if non-Optional return value is valid?

Tags: swift

I've run into an odd case when trying to check a return value, and I'm wondering how to do this "properly", in the Swift sense.

I have an `NSStatusItem` (named `item`), and I'm trying to assign the `NSStatusItem` an `NSImage`. When I make the `NSImage`, since I pass it a string value for the image name, I want to make sure that the `NSImage` is actually valid (what if I mistype the image name string?).

The first thing I tried was this:

```
if let image: NSImage? = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName") {
    item.image = image
}
```

But this gives the error "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type". I thought that saying `image: NSImage?` made it clear that it was Optional, but I guess not.

I changed that to this:

```
let image: NSImage? = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
if image {
     item.image = image
}
```

Which works totally fine. But I don't get why this works, while the first example doesn't. It seems more-or-less to be the exact same thing. And since the first one didn't compile, I thought I'd try some other routes...

Since `NSImage(named:)` does return an `NSImage` and not an `NSImage?`, I thought I'd see what happened if I assigned the return value of the constructor directly to `item`:

```
item.image = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
```

Which works, but doesn't allow for the error checking I want to do. If the string is wrong, the `NSStatusItem` gets `nil` for an image, which leads to me having an invisible status bar item.

Next, I tried this:

```
let image: NSImage = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
if image {
    item.image = image
}
```

But this gives the error "Type 'NSImage' does not confirm to protocol 'LogicValue'", which I guess means you aren't allowed to check if it's `nil` or not with an if statement.

However, you can check whether it is nil by doing the following:

```
let image: NSImage = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
if image != nil {
    item.image = image
}
```

So, here's the question: how exactly is one *supposed* to check a return value if it isn't Optional?

Comment: Good question, but I think the *real* question here is: Why does `init(name:)` return `NSImage`? I believe the answer is simply:"Its a bug with the automatic ObjC -> Swift header generator, file a bug report!"

Comment: @JackWu, it's possible this behavior is a bug too. I'm not sure though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It actually *is* Optional, the compiler just isn't showing it to you.

In Apple's documentation about working with Objective-C objects, it says that all objects imported from Objective-C APIs are actually implicitly unwrapped optionals (like we would manually declare with `!`):

> In some cases, you might be absolutely certain that an Objective-C
>   method or property never returns a `nil` object reference. To make
>   objects in this special scenario more convenient to work with, Swift
>   imports object types as *implicitly unwrapped optionals*. Implicitly
>   unwrapped optional types include all of the safety features of
>   optional types. In addition, you can access the value directly without
>   checking for `nil` or unwrapping it yourself. [[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_31)]

Unfortunately, the compiler/syntax checker doesn't treat them as such. Therefore, the correct way of checking would be to declare `image` as the type that the `NSImage` initializer is actually returning, an implicitly unwrapped optional `NSImage`:

```
let image: NSImage! = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
if image {
    // do something
}
```

Alternate method (via @vacawama):

```
if let image = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName") as NSImage! {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Nate is correct.  You can also do:    if let image = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName") as NSImage! {
        item.image = image
    }

Comment: So when the documentation talks about "Objective-C methods" or "Objective-C objects", it is also talking about Cocoa/Cocoa Touch methods/objects? (I assumed Cocoa/Cocoa Touch was Swift-ified, and that working with it was not "interacting with Objective-C APIs".)

Also, is the fact the compiler/syntax checker doesn't treat these objects as implicitly unwrapped optionals a bug that should be filed? The API says it returns `NSImage`, not `NSImage?` or `NSImage!`.

Comment: Yeah - it means methods and objects that are defined in an Objective-C API. The issue is that all objects in Objective-C can be `nil`, unlike Swift. It seems like a lot of the Optional functionality built into Swift is specifically to bridge that divide between the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of a mismatch between Objective-C initializers which may return nil and Swift's init semantics.  If you invoke  SomeObject(...) it's defined by the language to create an instance of `SomeObject` NOT `SomeObject?`

There are a few examples of initializers in the Cocoa/Foundation frameworks that, from a Swift perspective, generate an `NSSomething?` not the implied `NSSomething`

There are myriad way for Apple to address this without compromising the Swift type system, but until they do, there are several ways for you to "Do the Right Thing."

Re-wrap the object in a conditional - this works but is clunky:

```
var maybeImage: NSImage? = NSImage(named: "CorrectIconName")
if let image = maybeImage {

}
```

Better is to make your own function for loading NSImage

```
func loadImageNamed(name: String) -> NSImage? {
    return NSImage(named: name)
}

func doSomethingWithAnImage() {
    if let image = loadImageNamed( "CorrectIconName") {
        ....
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can extend NSImage.

```
extension NSImage {
    class func imageWithName(name: String) -> NSImage? {
        return NSImage(named: name)
    }
}
```

Now you can do the natural thing.

```
if let image = NSImage.imageWithName("CorrectIconName") {
}
```

This seems to be the right thing for the Swift/Cocoa API and I hope Apple does something similar in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something completely obvious, this is more a matter of opinion. You should probably be storing the return in a variable and then checking the contents of that variable. I think this is mostly because what if that variable ended up not being declared if the return was optional? The if statement would have a fit!

This is pertaining to the first part of your question, which also seems like the rest of your question, but I might be confused...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in IOS and solved it using the ?-operator:

```
if let im = UIImage(named: "Meetup.png")? {
    imageLayer.contents = im.CGImage
}
```

Without the the ? it would not enter the if branch, but when using ? it does !