# How can I avoid the Optional.None error in this scenario?

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift

```
var image = self.imageData[index] as NSString     
        if let derp = image as NSString? {
            println(" \(image)")
        } else {
            println("is nil")
        }

        dataViewController.dataImage.image = UIImage(named: image) as UIImage
```

That last line:

`dataViewController.dataImage.image = UIImage(named: image) as UIImage`

gives me "Can't unwrap Optional.None", despite the image object successfully passing the optional binding test as shown here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_428 . The image string does print at the bottom of Xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly check if non-Optional return value is valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439773/how-to-properly-check-if-non-optional-return-value-is-valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you are getting that error because an image with that name does not exist. However, you also have some issues with your optional binding.

1. Optional binding is different from casting. You don't provide a new type. Also, even if casting was the way to do it, you are casting to an optional, which doesn't prove that `image` is not nil.
2. You have already asserted to the compiler that image is not nil with your `as NSString` on the first line. If this conversion is not successful at runtime, your whole app will crash.
3. After binding an optional, you should use the local variable, not use the optional later

This means your code should look like this:

```
var possibleImageName = self.imageData[index] as? NSString     
if let imageName = possibleImageName {
    var possibleImage : UIImage? = UIImage(named: imageName)
    if let image = possibleImage {
        dataViewController.dataImage.image = image
    }
} else {
    println("is nil")
}
```

After you understand the optional binding process, and the difference from casting, you can shorten the code to this:

```
if let imageName = self.imageData[index] as? NSString {
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) as UIImage? {
        dataViewController.dataImage.image = image
    }
} else {
    println("is nil")
}
```

**Note:** The check for nil from initializers is strange. You have to cast it to be an optional type so that you can actually test it because initializers from Objective-C actually return [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_436).

Comment: I get an error: "Bound value in a conditional must be of Optional type", for that final example.

Comment: @user3784622 ya, I just tested that. I forgot that you can't treat initializers as optional. I updated my answer.

Comment: Goodness, I am finding this Optionals stuff confusing! How did you take the time to understand them? Is the swift manual the best option for the time being? Thanks.

Comment: your code won't work when the error caused in unwrapping `UIImage` returned from `UIImage(named: imageName)`. check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24440135/642626)

Comment: @user3784622 for me it was a combination of reading the swift manual and also lurking on stack overflow ;)

Comment: @drewag You may be applying additional edits however your current code displays `dataViewController.dataImage.image = image` as having the original error.

Comment: @user3784622 I don't know which code you used because I was making changes, but I tested my code above and it works fine. If you are still getting that error then perhaps `dataImage` is nil.

Comment: That is very odd, because my image is in the asset catalogue.. It is called "page1" and whether I use the contents of that array[index] or "page1.png" it causes the same error.

Comment: @user3784622 it is possible that the `dataImage` property on `dataViewController` is an optional and is nil. So it may have nothing to do with the image.

Comment: dataImage is an @IBOutlet. Does that make a difference?     `@IBOutlet var dataImage : UIImageView` is in the dataViewController's class. It is connected as denoted by the circular indicator on the left.

Comment: @user3784622 yes, perhaps the outlet is not connected

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage(named:)` may return `nil` in case the image with given name cannot be found. You need to check it did not nil.

```
var img : UIImage? = UIImage(named: image)
if img != nil {
    dataViewController.dataImage.image = img!
}
```

or

```
if let img = UIImage(named: image) as UIImage! {
    dataViewController.dataImage.image = img
}
```

Comment: Why make `img` an implicitly unwrapped optional? Especially in the second case, you can make it non-optional because you are using an optional binding.

Comment: @drewag why not? and for second case, I am not 100% sure drop optional it will work and I can't test it now.

Comment: In the first case, if something can truly be nil, then you should always use an actual optional, then the compiler forces you to unwrap it. In the second case, an implicitly unwrapped optional is doing literally nothing. Best case, it is just more verbose. Although I just test this myself and you can't treat an initializer as if it were optional so neither version will compile.

Comment: you are right for first case. but for second case you are wrong. it is workaround that constructor return non-optional value by default

Comment: Yup you're right, I didn't realize there was a way to test a initializer for nil, thank you.